# can't do remote-debugging with j-link in Clion IDE

Tags: remote-debugging, clion

I am trying to remote-debug a project in Clion but I can't seem to get a working debugging session. I think I've correctly launched my gdb server/client because my gdb client connects to the JLinkGDBServerCL.exe process 
and they communicate.However, in clion, I can't break in the source code. The only thing that I get from clion is a disassembly of my program with no symbol at all which is odd because there is a symbol table in the .elf
that I am trying to debug. And one last detail, I can't "step in" the assembly code neither (but I can run commands in the gdb client in Clion).

Here is a picture of my debug configuration : [debug config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdrtJ.png)

And here is what I'm talking about when I say I can't get a proper debugging session : ["debugging session"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJwdv.png)

Does anybody know what the problem is ?

System info:

- OS: Windows 10
- IDE: Clion 2018.1.6
- GDB Server: JLinkGDBServerCL.exe
- Target: TM4C129 (cortex M4) (no OS, just a firmware)
- Program: USBMicroloader.elf (debug mode)

Comment: In order to debug this kind of issues I'd set up a [symbolic breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-breakpoints.html) pointing to some predefined function, which is know to be called, like `main`, or some kind of an event loop in case of an embedded application. When it's triggered, GDB writes the source path of the corresponding symbol/address to the GDB console (a tab next to variables). If CLion opens disasm instead of the proper source for such a breakpoint, please check that the reported source file exists on the machine, otherwise you need to setup path mappings.

Comment: ok thank you for this advice. Can't wait to try it ! Maybe I will have the time to do it today. I will post the results as soon as possible.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov I did what you told me, but the debugger doesn't even hit the breakpoint. There is no way to launch the program with the debugger tool (for whatever reason). You told me to set-up path mapping but what is it exactly ? I mean its the mapping of server's paths to local paths but correct me if I am wrong my jlinkgdbserver is running on my host as well as the debugger ? So what is it exactly in that case, a 1:1 mapping ?

Comment: https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/debug/jlink/ it's Eclipse, but a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I found that if I add the path to the elf file from the build directory into the "Symbol file" (in the run configuration where you set up the remote gdb connection), it fixes your issue. This seems a bit kludgey, but I haven't been able to find a better solution.

However, the next issue I run into is that I can only run that configuration a single time. When I stop debugging I get a message in the console that reads `Remote doesn't know how to detach. Debugger disconnected.` The clean and build menu options are greyed out until I restart CLion.